# How to include a photo in Moderncv Casual

Tags: latex, pdflatex

Well, to start with, I don't know much about Latex. I am failing to include a picture in to the document using "Moderncv Casual". A lot of the CV's and cover letter's template using:

```
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{filename}
```

What's the deal with this? Is it not just to type the pictures's filename, compile, and the picture should be added to the document?

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly it. The `\photo` macro is set up in such a way that it stores your input and makes it part of the CV title (set with `\makecvtitle`).

The reasoning behind this is to provide the end-user with a generic command to would capture a picture. However, depending on the template used, this picture may appear on the left/right/middle (or wherever). The generic input abstracts this placement from the rest of the code.

Specific to the command `\photo`; it is defined inside the class [`moderncv.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncv.cls) file as:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\photo}{O{64pt}O{0.4pt}m}
  {\def\@photowidth{#1}\def\@photoframewidth{#2}\def\@photo{#3}}
```

An input like

```
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{filename}
```

defines the photo to be kept in `\@photo` - it references the image file `filename` (with an image extension) - to have a width of `64pt` (stored in `\@photowidth`) and frame width `0.4pt` (stored in `\@photoframewidth`).

Comment: For me, the `\photo` command does nothing. It just doesn't show any photo and also does not throw any error. I double-checked the path, but it should be ok. I use the `banking` theme and a `.jpg` photo. Any idea what's the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: @CGFoX: `\photo` just stores the information of the photo, but doesn't set anything. It will be set with a call to `\makecvtitle`. Unless you just want to include a random image in your document, for which you can use `\includegraphics[<opts>]{<file>}`.